# Is the laplace transform $L(t\cdot e^{-t})$ same as $L(t) \cdot L(e^{-t})$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is the laplace transform $L(t\cdot e^{-t})$ same as $L(t) \cdot L(e^{-t})$? Because if you do $L(t\cdot e^{-t})$ using First Translation Theorem, you arrive at $$\frac{1}{(s+1)^{2}}.$$ But if you do $L(t) \cdot L(e^{-t})$ using the convolution theorem, you get 
$$\frac{1}{s^2} \cdot \frac{1}{s+1}.$$

How is it that they are not the same? Both are valid theorems.... Please refrain from using completed explanations and be as simple as possible. Thank you!

Comment: No, the Laplace transform of a product is not the product of the Laplace transforms.

Comment: @copper.hat Can't you do it using the convolution theorem?

Comment: You can, but that is not just straight multiplication as you have above.

Answer (score 2):

Laplace transformation of the **convolution** (not the product) of two functions equals the **product** of Laplace transformation of each function.

Comment: @copper.hat I just now confused with that in probability theory. Shame on me.

Comment: I still don't quite understand. t and e^-t are both functions, then why can't you use convolution theorem on them and take laplace transform of each function and multiply? Could you show examples?

Comment: @JoMo Convolution law is for convolution of functions, but $te^{-t}$ is not a convolution.

Comment: How come? Could you give me an example of convolution of functions? t and e^-t are both functions though.... How about te^t, would you be able to use convolution theorem on that?

Comment: @JoMo Convolution $F(t)$ of $f$ and $g$ is defined as $\int f(x)g(t-x)dx$

Answer (score 1):

We have  $\displaystyle L(e^{at})=\frac1{s-a}$

We know, $\displaystyle L(e^{at}f(t))=F(s-a)$ where $F(s)=L(f(t))$

So as $\displaystyle L(t^n)=\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}},$ for integer $n,$
$\displaystyle L(e^{at} t^n)=\frac{n!}{(s-a)^{n+1}}$

So, $L(t^n)\cdot L(e^{at})\ne  L(e^{at} t^n)$

Comment: I still don't quite understand. t and e^-t are both functions, then why can't you use convolution theorem on them and take laplace transform of each function and multiply? Could you show examples?

Answer (score 0):

Call $f_1(t)=t$ and $f_2(t)=\mathrm{e}^{-t}$.
The point that you missed is that the convolution theorem states that $L_s(f_1)\,L_s(f_2)$ is the Laplace transform of
$$f(t)=\int_0^t f_1(u)\,f_2(t-u)\,\mathrm{d}u=\int_0^t\;u\;\mathrm{e}^{-(t-u)}\,\mathrm{d}u=\mathrm{e}^{-t}-1+t.$$

Take the Laplace transform of $f$ and you find
$$ L_s\big(f(t)\big)=\frac1{s+1}-\frac1{s}+\frac1{s^2}=\frac{1}{s^2(s+1)}.$$